# Edit Id - Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So I need to be able to edit my primary key field in my edit page for a row, I get the error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement 
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). 
>   Entities may have been modified or deleted
>   since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

When I don't change the primary key field I can save all my other changes to my database.

This is my edit function.

```
//edit - post
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActiveCampaignsEdit(ActiveCampaign activecampaign)
{
  try
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      db.Entry(activecampaign).State = EntityState.Modified;
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("ActiveCampaigns");
    }
  }
  catch (DataException err)
  {
    //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, err.Message);
  }
  ViewBag.TypesList = new SelectList(db.Types, "TypeId", "TypeName");
  ViewBag.CaptureFormsList = new SelectList(db.CaptureForms, "Id", "Name");
  ViewBag.AssignedUsersList = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Username");
  return View(activecampaign);
}
```

How would I go about editing the Primary Key, or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  The question seems valid and articulate to me.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it has been asked before? I've spent the past hour trying to find a way to fix it(searching this site and google), no luck.

Comment: Why do you want to change the primary key? EF uses the primary key to identify the record to update. When you change it, it will not be able  to do the update

Comment: I need to access a row based on a tag number, not an Id(if that makes sense). The tag number needs to be editable and unique, I also have to pass the tag number to the view, rather than the Id. Have I gone about this the wrong way? Writing it out now, it sounds like I have.

Comment: @GaryKenyon: If it was asked before, the right thing to do is to vote to close with a reference to the original question, not downvote a legitimate question (though some people will downvote if it is a very obvious duplicate, e.g. one that shows up as related questions while you are typing in your questions).

Comment: @EricJ: There are related questions with, that bring up the same error message, but I couldn't find any that were directly related to my issue. I'm fairly new to Stackoverflow(posting that is), so I'm trying to stick to the rules as much as I can!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using ORMs like Entity Framework, the UPDATE command is composed basically like this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET ChangedCol = ChangedVal 
WHERE PrimaryKeyCol = PrimaryKeyValAtLoadTime
```

Afterwards it checks the number of affected rows to match the expected value.

So when you try to change the PK the update command will update no row and the check will fail.

The real question is: Why do you want to change the primary key value?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Save(object entity)
        {
            using (var transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
            try
                    {
                        SaveChanges();
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
                    {
                        if (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Deleted || ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Modified)
                            this.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);
                        else if (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Added)
                            Detach(entity);
                        AcceptAllChanges(); 
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
            }
        }
```