# Unable to update model in MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to update entity but it is giving me an error like "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."
i have searched internet but couldn't found any appropriate solution. i'm sharing my code:

Action Method:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EditCustomTicket([Bind(Include = @"TicketDetailId,GenericOrderId,PartId,Quantity,CustomerPrice,
                                                                             Status,RowVersion,PersonID,Notes,Manufacturer,DateCode,
                                                                             Package,CustomQuantity,BuyingPrice,CustomPrice,LTDays,
                                                                             Description")] TicketDetail orderdetail, int? id, string request)
        {
            TryUpdateModel(orderdetail);
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.TicketDetails.Attach(orderdetail);
                    var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;

                    manager.ChangeObjectState(orderdetail, EntityState.Modified);

                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                TempData["Error"] = string.Format(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.Source);
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
            }
            return View(orderdetail);
        }
```

THis is the view:

```
<div>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("EditCustomTicket")">

                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.TicketDetailId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.GenericOrderId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Notes)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Status)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.PersonID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.RowVersion)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Quantity)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.CustomerPrice)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.PartId)


                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Part.PartNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Part.PartNumber)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Manufacturer, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Manufacturer, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "textbox" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Manufacturer)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.DateCode, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.DateCode, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "textbox" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.DateCode)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Package, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Package, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "textbox" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Package)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Quantity, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Quantity)
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Package, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Package, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "textbox" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Package)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.BuyingPrice, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.BuyingPrice, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "textbox" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.BuyingPrice)
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <span id="bpusd"></span>

                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.CustomPrice, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.CustomPrice, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "textbox" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.CustomPrice)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span id="amtusd"></span>
                        <div class="form-group float">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.LTDays, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 lab" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.LTDays, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "textbox" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.LTDays)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />


                        <input class="btn green butt" value="Send Quote" type="submit" />
                        <input class="btn yellow butt" value="Send Performa INV." type="submit" />
                        <input class="btn blue butt" value="Send Invoice" type="submit" />



                        <hr />
                    </form>
                }
            </div>
```

it is a partial view. please guide me with this.

Comment: The exception probably means that the key property of the `orderdetail` that you attach (`orderdetail.TicketDetailId`? Or is the key even composite?) does not have a correct value of an existing record in the database. You should investigate that in the debugger.

Comment: @Slauma it has the correct value, i have checked this in debugger. how do i solve this issue? i have added row version property to avoid optimistic concurrency conflicts

Comment: And is the RowVersion property correctly set before you attach? What did you use as RowVersion? A byte array? Or something custom?

Comment: @Slauma a byte array, everything set properly, can u please tell me how this error will be solved?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586995/edit-id-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpected-numbe?rq=1

Comment: @PranavSingh i have checked this before asking question, well i think there is no one efficient enough here to solve complex problems, all her can only solve basic things

Comment: I have no clue how this exception could be thrown in this situation other than when **the primary key values or the row version don't match** with the record in the DB. You say, they are "set properly". You should check that really exactly, ideally using a SQL profiler that shows you the SQL UPDATE statement that is sent to the DB, especially if that statement indeed has the correct WHERE clause including the valid PK value and the valid row version. The exception simply means that the DB engine says this WHERE clause is false for all rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the data is not changed or you don't include the primary key field.

Comment: i have included the primary key field, i have updated the question please check

Answer (score 0):

You aren't attaching to an existing entity.

You need to specify which entity it is that you're working with before you can attach the ticket details to it e.g.

```
var existingTicket = db.TicketDetails.Find(Id);

existingTicket.Attach(orderdetail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the Bind attribute in your

> EditCustomTicket

method. You can try something else to handle the mass assignment problem.